# Why am I getting error CS0120 if I have no "static" in my code?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I'm making a FPS game and I was trying some scripts for the guns but Unity keeps showing the error CS0120 but the problem is that I'm not using anything "static" or that needs it, at least I think I'm not using.

Main code:

```
{
    public float damage = 10f;
    public float range = 100f;

    public Camera fpsCam;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
        {
            Shoot();
        }
    }

    void Shoot()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(fpsCam.transform.position, fpsCam.transform.forward, out hit, range))
        {
            Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);

            healthPoints hp = hit.transform.GetComponent<healthPoints>();
            if(hp != null)
            {
                //Here is where I get the error
                healthPoints.TakeDamage(damage);
            }

        }
    }

}
```

HP code:

```
public class healthPoints : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float health = 100f;

    public void TakeDamage(float amount)
    {
        health -= amount;

        if (health <= 0f)
        {
            Die();
        }
    }

    void Die()
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

"Error  CS0120  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'healthPoints.TakeDamage(float)'"

Comment: you have an instance named `hp`, yet you call `healthPoints.TakeDamage()` on the class instead of the instance

Comment: The error tells you what you need to do; since the `TakeDamage` method is not `static`, you need to use a reference to the `healthPoints` class in order to call it (which you have in `hp`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with this code snippet is, that you have to use the instantiated object `hp`, not the class `healthPoints` to call the non-static method `TakeDamage()`:

```
if(hp != null)
{
   // Here is where I get the error
   hp.TakeDamage(damage);
}
```

Only static methods of a class can be accessed without instantiating an object first of the class.